# What happens if two people tie?

Tags: just-dance-3

(This should apply to any game other than the original Just Dance, but I'm asking about Just Dance 3 if you need something specifically.)

I see a lot of videos with people getting all Perfects. However, I never see two people get all Perfects in the same video.

Let's say Alice and Bob play and they get the exact same ratings for moves. (For example, every time Alice gets an OK, Bob does too.)

What happens then? Does the game not "crown" a winner? Or is there something else that happens?

Comment: Just an idea: start the song with both controllers being on a table, and do not touch them until the end of the song. They should get the same score.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard I've done that before and gotten 0 for both players. However, I'm looking to see what happens if both players do something such as getting only one Perfect and then all Xs afterwards. I saw some Just Dance 2 gameplay and it looks to me like there's some small random point addition when you score on a move.